# Google App Engine serves wrong HTTPS certificate for default domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine where I deploy different services, but for some services wrong certificates are provided.

I haven't understood when a deploy *fails*, but when a service deploy doesn't work, it doesn't matter if I try to deploy it again, it continues to do not work.

**Standard behavior**:

- The app is deployed to `https://<service>-dot-<project>.appspot.com`
- Everything works fine

**Faulty behavior**:

- The app is deployed to `https://service.project.appspot.com` (**notice that the url has a `.` instead of `-dot-`**
- The url with `-dot-` is not resolved
- The url where the app is deployed serves a certificate for `*.appspot-preview.com`, and I cannot go around it 'cause there is HSTS

The GCP console doesn't report anything: everywhere in the console links go to the supposedly correct url (the one with `-dot-`), giving me an unresolved domain. The only place where the effective url is shown is in the terminal after the deployment

I deploy with `gcloud app deploy --project ${PROJECT} --version ${COMMIT_SHA}`, and my `app.yaml` is:

```
runtime: python27
service: <service_name>
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  secure: always

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
  secure: always
```

Comment: The URL is not *where* the service is deployed, is what the service answers to (or doesn't, if it's faulty enough). Try using the version# (COMMIT_SHA) of a faulty version but while deploying a good one (otherwise the bad one remains, of course, bad). But I can't imagine how can a static-only site be faulty, tho. Can you show a faulty deployment log?

Comment: @DanCornilescu the deploy is successful, the only difference in logs between a working deployment and a faulty one is the URL it says to reach. If I deploy a commit to a working service, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations I've found the culprit: in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref), section `service`, it says (emphasis mine):

> Each service and each version must have a name. A name can contain
> numbers, letters, and hyphens. **It cannot be longer than 63 characters**
> and cannot start or end with a hyphen. Choose a unique name for each
> service and each version. Don't reuse names between services and
> versions.

This is not entirely accurate, because per [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), each DNS label can contain up to 63 characters, and in our case subdomain is `<service>-dot-<project>`, meaning that `<service>-dot-<project>` cannot be longer than 63 characters, so `service`cannot be longer than `(63 - len(project) - 5)` chars.

I was using services name shorter than 63 chars, but longer than  `(63 - len(project) - 5)`. Shorting the service name fix the problem.

Comment: Nice catch! You may want to be even stricter, to allow [targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing) - in which the service versions are also included in the URL - to work.

Comment: Hello @rpadovani! If this answer you found is satisfactory for your issue, could you accept it so that it gets a better visibility for other users that may have the same issue?